# Apportable> AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker> Undeclared Identifier Error

Tags: avaudiosession, apportable

I am trying my first build for android using Apportable, from a simple iOS app. Getting the following error:

```
    use of undeclared identifier 'AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker'
```

The code in my iOS app is as following:

```
    if([session respondsToSelector:@selector(overrideOutputAudioPort:error:)])
[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&setOverrideError];
```

Can somebody guide me how I should change my objective C code to make it work with Apportable?

Answer (score 0):

you forget to import module

```
@import AVFoundation;
```